# What should I write as a contact reference person if the inviting organization is a university in Schengen area?

Tags: visas, schengen, germany, schengen-visas, business-travel

I am applying for a Business Schengen visa. Going for a workshop at a university in Germany. I filled the reference info. However, they are asking for a contact person, who should I write their info in that case?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What did the university / workshop organiser say when you asked them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They want a person who they can contact to confirm what you say. Give them the name of the person who actually invited you, or the name of the workshop organizer. Give the address and phone for the workshop.

Comment: Or the office phone number for that person.

Comment: It's probably worth contacting the individual or institution to confirm this. People don't always like their personal details being given out without permission or notification. And they may have experience of how best to apply for a visa.