# B1/B2 Visa Application: Assistance in Providing Funding Entity Contact Information

Tags: visas, usa, paperwork, b1-b2-visas, applications

I am currently finalizing my DS-160 B1/B2 US visa application to visit the US to attend a workshop for 5 days in the US. In the invitation letter I received from the non-profit organization that is hosting the workshop, it is written that my scholarship is funded by BP, a global integrated energy company and a sponsor of the conference.

My question is:
Regarding filling in the information about the entity paying for my trip, do I submit the contact details for BP, the corporate sponsor, or the non-profit organization receiving the sponsorship?

Comment: Why does BP give you a scholarship? A sort of hiring process, or PR, or corporate workshop for new employee, or what? As you see, it may really depend on the reason, and who give you the money (a local branch, or a global department). Note: often such companies for international workshop will help you on visa, try to ask them.

Comment: Is BP sponsoring you *personally* ie directly? It sounds like they are sponsoring the event itself, not the individual(s) attending it. ‘Scholarship’ sounds odd in the context of a 5 day workshop in the US. Why were you invited, what expenses does your ‘scholarship’ include, and from where are you applying for the visa? The organisation that issued your invitation should be able to tell you what information to provide. Similar to your Schengen workshop question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/184288/what-should-i-write-as-a-contact-reference-person-if-the-inviting-organization-i

Answer (score 7):

**Ask the company what information you should provide.**

In general the name of the company should be the formal name of the company in your country. It will be on any letters, contracts or agreements that you have received. The phone number should be the business number of the person you have been dealing with at the company. The address should be the office address of the person you have been dealing with at the company.

"Relationship to you" depends on why you are getting the scholarship. If you are an employee then write "employer". If you got the scholarship because you won a student prize, write "Sponsor of XYZ Prize for excellence in Petroleum" (or whatever the prize was). Unless you are their employee you will need to give additional details of why they are sponsoring you. It's highly likely that BP can advise you on what to wrote here if you are not sure.